# Arabic text in \begin{arab} displays properly but titles, sections, and everything else doesn't

Tags: sectioning, xetex, arabic

Titles and Sections are not displayed properly in Arabic. They are shown as separated characters while other parts of the document is displayed perfectly.

If I remove `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}`, nothing gets displayed when it is processed with XeLaTeX besides the text within `\begin{arab}`, however, `\section{التعليمات}` is still separated characters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[pdfauthor={Yousef Raffa},pdftitle={Translation of The ARRL LoTW Registration Instructions in Arabic}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{arabxetex}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\pagestyle{headings}

\title{ترجمة لتعليمات التسجيل في \textLR{ARRL LoTW}\\ \textLR{Translation of ARRL LoTW Registration
Instructions in Arabic}}
\author{يوسف عدنان رفـّـه\and Yousef A. Raffah}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % No page number on 1st page

\begin{arab}

\section{التعليمات}

اتبع الخطوات التالية لإتمام عملية إنشاء حسابك الخاص في دفتر سجلات العالم 
\textLR{Logbook of the World}.

\subsection{الخطوة الأولى - تنزيل و تهيئة البرنامج}

دفتر سجلات العالم \textLR{Logbook of the World} يستخدم برنامج اسمه \textLR{TrustedQSL} وهو

\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[Here is a link to the Amiri font I'm using](http://www.amirifont.org)

**UPDATE:**

If I `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Geeza Pro}` the output displays titles and sections properly but English characters are squares now and so are section numbers!

[image: Screenshot showing the problem of separated characters]
[image: Screenshot of what happens if I remove \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}]
[image: Screenshot of output when \setmainfont is changed to Geeza Pro]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `polyglossia` instead of `arabxetex` and set the main document language to Arabic and the secondary language to English, for English text you will now have to use `\textenglish` instead of `textLR`. Refer to `polyglossia` package documentation for more details.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdfauthor={Yousef Raffa},pdftitle={Translation of The ARRL LoTW Registration Instructions in Arabic}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\pagestyle{headings}

\title{ترجمة لتعليمات التسجيل في \textenglish{ARRL LoTW}\\ \textenglish{Translation of ARRL LoTW Registration
Instructions in Arabic}}
\author{يوسف عدنان رفـّـه\and Yousef A. Raffah}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % No page number on 1st page

\section{التعليمات}
اتبع الخطوات التالية لإتمام عملية إنشاء حسابك الخاص في دفتر سجلات العالم 
\textenglish{Logbook of the World}.

\subsection{الخطوة الأولى - تنزيل و تهيئة البرنامج}
دفتر سجلات العالم \textenglish{Logbook of the World} يستخدم برنامج اسمه \textenglish{TrustedQSL} وهو
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Khaled-Hosny for your suggestion and it did the job as expected. It is good to see you again :)

Comment: @HZ1YR, this is probably not the best place for such chatting, but I’m glad we have (virtually) met again `:)`.